# Android EditTextView addTextChangedListener падает

Tags: java, android

Хочу по мере ввода отправлять запрос, для этого editText добавил addTextChangedListener, в котором объявил TextWatcher.

Но приложение падает:

**Ошибка**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.itunesapp, PID: 4443
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.itunesapp/com.example.itunesapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.itunesapp.result.ResultFragment.onViewCreated(ResultFragment.java:51)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1471)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1333)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6992)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Код:

```
public class ResultFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView mRecycler;
    private EditText mSearchETV;
    private final ResultAdapter mResultAdapter = new ResultAdapter();
    private List<Result> mResultList;


    public static ResultFragment newInstance() {
        return new ResultFragment();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_recycler, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mRecycler = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        mSearchETV = view.findViewById(R.id.etv_search);

        mSearchETV.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String searchText = mSearchETV.getText().toString();
                getResult(searchText);

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });


    }
....
}
```

Понимаю что, edittext = null, но я ему правильно указал Id

**XML**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etv_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/tv_track_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_collection_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_artist_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Может кто объяснить из-за чего падает приложение?

Comment: Проверьте, что в `R.layout.fr_recycler` действительно есть `view` с id `R.id.etv_search`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы в методе `onCeateView()` "раздули" методом `inflate()` layout вашего RecyclerView, где у вас нет вашего EditView, а в методе `onViewCreated()` вы пытаетесь его получить. Отсюда и NullPointerException.

Comment: да вы правы, я что-то тупанул)